# When does the export statement runs in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, node-modules

When does the export statement run? Is it before callbacks run. In that case, var1 and var2 will be undefined. Or is it after callbacks are completed?

```
let var1 = someAsyncFunction(param1).then( result => anotherFunction(result));
let var2 = someAsyncFunction(param2).then( result => anotherFunction(result));

export {var1 ,var2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it before callbacks run.

Yes.

> In that case, var1 and var2 will be undefined.

No. The `then` method returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It doesn't return `undefined`.